# How can i compare between two enums?

Tags: c#

This is my code,

```
[Flags]
public enum Colors { None = 0, Red = 1, Yellow = 2, Blue = 4, Green = 8, Orange = 16, Brown = 32, Cyan = 64, Magenta = 128, Other = 256 };



class Program
{
    Colors familyRGB = Colors.Red | Colors.Blue | Colors.Green;
    Colors familyCMY = Colors.Cyan | Colors.Magenta | Colors.Yellow;
    Colors familyRYB = Colors.Red | Colors.Blue | Colors.Yellow;
```

I have to write a method that takes two families as parameters and does few things
so i did this

```
public static void TwoFamilyColorSystem(Colors family1, Colors family2)
```

I would like to Print the element that exist in family 1 and does not exist in family 2.
How do I do that?
So for example, if I take RGB and RYB it should print green, because green exists in RGB and not RYB.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`~` inverts the bits. so:

```
return (Colors)(family1 & ~family2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it, it will return an enumerable of every enum value that belongs to just one (and exactly one) of the two families given:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Colors> TwoFamilyColorSystem(Colors family1, Colors family2)
{
    foreach(Colors value in Enum.GetValues<Colors>())
        if(family1.HasFlag(value) && !family2.HasFlag(value))
            yield return value;
}
```

Comment: OP does not ask for the inverse. Only those in first that aren't in second

Comment: Fair enough, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Since the question <strike>is</strike>was tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java), this is how you would do it in Java:

```java
public enum Colors {
    None(0), Red(1), Yellow(2), Blue(4), Green(8), Orange(16), Brown(32), Cyan(64), Magenta(128), Other(256);

    public static final Set<Colors> familyRGB = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Red, Blue, Green));
    public static final Set<Colors> familyCMY = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Cyan, Magenta, Yellow));
    public static final Set<Colors> familyRYB = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Red, Blue, Yellow));

    private final int flag;

    private Colors(int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public int getFlag() {
        return this.flag;
    }

    public Set<Colors> toFamily() {
        return EnumSet.of(this);
    }

    /**
     * Return colors in {@code a} that are not in {@code b}.
     */
    public static Set<Colors> subtract(Set<Colors> a, Set<Colors> b) {
        EnumSet<Colors> c = EnumSet.copyOf(a);
        c.removeAll(b);
        return c;
    }
}
```

<sup>*The `flag` value is unused for this and might be eliminated, but is kept here in case it would be used for other purposes.*</sup>

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(Colors.subtract(Colors.familyRGB, Colors.familyRYB));
System.out.println(Colors.subtract(Colors.familyRGB, Colors.Blue.toFamily()));
```

*Output*

```
[Green]
[Red, Green]
```